# Issues with variable used in reading binary file

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I'm writing some serial port code and need to read the contents of a file (in binary) to a variable.
Starting from the example for "Binary files" at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ ,
I try opening a .jpg file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream::pos_type size;
char * memblock;

int main () {
  ifstream file ("example.jpg", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
  if (file.is_open())
  {
    size = file.tellg();
    memblock = new char [size];
    file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
    file.read (memblock, size);
    file.close();

    cout << memblock << endl;

    delete[] memblock;
   }
 else cout << "Unable to open file";
 return 0;
}
```

However, only the first 4 characters (32 bits) are printed in the console.

What's particularly odd though is that using ostream::write() with that supposedly faulty variable "memblock" works perfectly:

```
ofstream fileOut ("writtenFile.jpg",ios::out|ios::binary);
fileOut.write(memblock,size);
fileOut.close();
```

ie it creates a new .jpg file.

So my question is why the memblock variable *seems* to only contain the first 4 characters.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a 0 in your binary data. `cout` is a text stream so looks at `memblock` as a string. If it reaches a null character then it thinks the string has finished.

See this for some help pin outputting binary data:
[How to make cout behave as in binary mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654067/918124)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  A quick glance at the page you cite shows that the author doesn't
know much about IO in C++.  Avoid it, since much of what it says is
wrong.

For the rest: `.jpg` is not a text format, and cannot be simply output
to `cout`.  When you use `<<`, of course, the output stops at the first
`'\0'` character, but all sorts of binary data may cause wierd effects:
data may be interpreted as an escape sequence repositionning the cursor,
locking the keyboard (actually happened to me once), etc.  These
problems will occur even if you use `std::cout.write()` (which will not
stop at the `'\0'` character).  If you want to visualize the data,
your best bet is some sort of binary dump.  (I use something like the
following for visualizing large blocks of data:

```
template <typename InputIterator>
void
process(
    InputIterator       begin,
    InputIterator       end,
    std::ostream&       output = std::cout )
{
    IOSave              saveAndRestore( output ) ;
    output.setf( std::ios::hex, std::ios::basefield ) ;
    output.setf( std::ios::uppercase ) ;
    output.fill( '0' ) ;
    static int const    lineLength( 16 ) ;
    while ( begin != end ) {
        int                 inLineCount = 0;
        unsigned char       buffer[ lineLength ] ;
        while ( inLineCount != lineLength && begin != end ) {
            buffer[inLineCount] = *begin;
            ++ begin;
            ++ inLineCount;
        }
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < lineLength ; ++ i ) {
            static char const *const
                                separTbl [] =
            {
                " ", " ", " ", " ",
                "  ", " ", " ", " ",
                "   ", " ", " ", " ",
                "  ", " ", " ", " ",
            } ; 
            output << separTbl[ i ] ;
            if ( i < inLineCount ) {
                output << std::setw( 2 )
                       << static_cast< unsigned int >(buffer[ i ] & 0xFF) ) ;
            } else {
                output << "  " ;
            }
        }
        output << " |" ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i != inLineCount ; ++ i ) {
            output << (i < lengthRead && isprint( buffer[ i ] )
                       ?   static_cast< char >( buffer[ i ] ) 
                       :   ' ') ;
        }
        output << '|' << std::endl ;
    }
}
```

(You'll also want to read into an `std::vector<char>`, so you don't have
to worry about freeing the memory.)