# c++ cout instead of fstream

Tags: c++, fstream, cout

Normally I live in my guarded world of C#. But sometimes I have to break out and do something outside.

At the moment I have to decode an audiostream and have to output this directly in my c++ console application.

If I write the content into a file, I can hear the correct result.
But if I use instead of a fstream cout, I get only a noisy sound.

How I have to do it correct?
Here the working filestream code:

```
fstream wavefile;
wavefile.open(output, ios::out | ios::binary | ios::trunc);

//do something
wavefile.write((char*) &waveheader, waveheadersize);
//do something else
do {
        //do something
        //decodedBuffer is of type BYTE* , decodedLength is of type DWORD
        wavefile.write((char*) decodedBuffer, decodedLength);
        wavefile.flush();
    } while (encodedLength > 0);
```

My not working cout code:

```
std::cout.setf(ios::out | ios::binary | ios::trunc);

//do something
//this works, I got the same output
cout << structToString(&waveheader) << endl;
//do something else
do {
        //do something
        cout << (char *)decodedBuffer;
    } while (encodedLength > 0);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: just redirect output when you use `std::cout` to a file and compare

Comment: None of `ios::out`, `ios::binary` and `ios::trunc` are formatting-flags. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf

Comment: You'll need to include the actual error message, to make this a valid question. _"Not working code"_ is too vague.

Comment: Let me guess, you are on windows, and thus textmode translation on your streams is killing your data.

Comment: And even if they were, `cout << (char *)decodedBuffer` invokes the formatted output inserter. You know `std::cout` still has a `write` method, right? It behaves as an [**unformatted output function**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/UnformattedOutputFunction), which is likely what you want (and in fact used in your `std::fstream` write operation using [`std::basic_ostream::write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write)).

Comment: When you use `cout << (char *)buffer;`, it treats the data as a zero-terminated string, which means it stops writing at the first zero-value byte. In a case like this where you could (and apparently do) have zero-value bytes in the middle of the buffer, that's not going to work.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654067/how-to-make-cout-behave-as-in-binary-mode

Comment: @WhozCraig: unfortunately you are wrong on Windows. line endings will be transformed to \r \n with cout. You need to set the mode to binary via `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, there is absolutely no reason to use different code for a `std::fstream` and for `std::cout` (Beside which, your `cout`-code uses formatted output, and wrong):

You are using their `ostream`-interface in both cases.

So, first things first, repair the second code (as far as possible) by replacing it with the first.

---

Now, we come to the one difference (which you tried to paper over with `setf`): `std::cout` is in **text-mode, not binary mode**!

Unfortunately, none of `ios::out`, `ios::binary` and `ios::trunc` are formatting-flags, so you cannot set them with [`setf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf).

Actually, the mode cannot be changed at all after the fact (at least not portably).

Fortunately, you can simply ignore having the wrong mode on many systems, as Linux and others equate textmode and binary-mode. On windows, this hack should get you around it:

```
cout.flush();
fflush(stdout);
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you can't.  You need to output in
binary mode.  The mode is selected, once and for all, when you
open the file, and `std::cout` is always opened in text mode.

Since you're just writing a block of bytes, the simplest
solution is to use the system level requests.  Under Windows,
for example, you can use `GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE )` to
get the handle to standard out, and `WriteFile` to write a block
of bytes to it.  (Under Unix, the file descriptor for standard
out is always `1`, and the function is `write`.  But since there
is no difference between text mode and binary mode under Unix,
I assume that this isn't your case.)

Comment: Certainly also a worthwhile idea to just drop down to the raw OS-API, though I guess he wanted to stay with an `ostream`-interface.

Comment: @Deduplicator It would be perhaps understandable for reasons of portability, but since there isn't a portable solution...

Answer (score -2):

Try this,

```
    std::cout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(decodedBuffer), decodedLength);
```

But I am not sure if structToString(&waveheader) work correctly, but you seem okay with it.

Comment: what he wants is to output a chuck of memory, starting from decodedBuffer, the length is decodedLength. Not string representation of the data.

Comment: Yes. But `cout` is in text-mode, thus his data will still be garbled.

Comment: At the end I used a mix of @Deduplicator and user3183610. So its not that bad. Thank you.